# What is the $P_o$ or $P_i$ in Bernouilli's equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

I've been learning about Bernoulli's equation:
$$P_i + pgh_i + p\frac{v_i^2}{2} = P_0 + pgh_0 + p\frac{v_0^2}{2}$$
but am confused about what $P_i$ and $P_0$ truly represent. Sal from Khan Academy said that they were the work done on the fluid, but other sources say static pressure and just pressure in general. Also, what does $pv_i^2/2$ represent? I've heard it means dynamic pressure, or kinetic energy (but then what's the difference between kinetic energy and dynamic pressure), and Merriam Webster defines it as "the pressure on a surface at which a flowing fluid is brought to rest in excess of the pressure on it when the fluid is not flowing," which is hard to visualize for me. Can anyone explain these two terms from Bernoulli's equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the hyper-physics link for Bernoulli's principle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/pber.html)

> The Bernoulli Equation can be considered to be a statement of the conservation of energy principle appropriate for flowing fluids.

You ask specifically about the terms $P_o$ and $P_i$ refer to. Simply put 'Initial' pressure and 'final' pressure.

I wish to point out here that the subscripts you are using when writing this equation down differ from convention. Instead of $o$ and $i$ typically the equation is written with $0$ and $1$ or $1$ and $2$. Respectively, these subscripts typically refer to the same point at two different times, or different points at the same time. When talking about the same point at two times I prefer the subscripts $0$ and $1$ or $i$ and $f$. I use the $0$ subscript to mean the 'initial' time when we set the value of our stopwatch to the time $t=0$, and the subscript $1$ means at some later time. I can make it very clear with $i$ and $f$ that we are talking about an initial time and a 'final' time.

Bernoulli's equation can be used to talk about either situation mentioned above, two different points at the same time and the same point at two different times. Regardless there is a more intuitive form for Bernoulli's equation. We can see it if we move everything over to one side:

\begin{align*}
0&= P_1 + \rho g h_1 + \frac{\rho}{2}v_1^2
- 
P_0 - \rho g h_0 - \frac{\rho}{2}v_0^2
\\
&=
P_1 - P_0 + \rho g (h_1 - h_0) + \frac{\rho}{2}(v_1^2-v_0^2)
\\
&=\Delta P + \Delta U + \Delta T = \Delta P + \Delta E = 0\\
&\rightarrow \Delta P = -\Delta E
\end{align*}

Where $\Delta U = \rho g \Delta h$ and $\Delta T = \frac{\rho}{2}(v_1^2-v_0^2)$ are the potential and kinetic *volumetric energy densities* of the fluid. To break this down into less conceptual language Bernoulli's principle says that a change in pressure in fluid is proportional to the change in the energy density of the fluid. As hyperphysics states, Bernoulli's principle expresses conservation of energy for fluids.

A very real physical example is water moving in pipes. When a water tower supplies water to the town it may either supply a little bit of high pressure water or it may release as much pressure as it holds and as the pipes will take. The greater the change in pressure  pipe than the other, the faster the fluid will leave. This applies more generally and even across the cross section of a pipe. Higher inside a large pipe, the fluid has more gravitational potential energy, if that piece of fluid moves slowly, then we can for example figure out say how high a pump can push water uphill.

What is important to know is that [PRESSURE IS THE SAME THING AS AN ENERGY DENSITY](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/press.html#ed). That is to say, pressure represents the ability for a fluid to do work just as much as kinetic or potential energy. In fact, pressure is one kind of potential energy. Since 'pressure' can be thought of as form of energy density, kinetic energy density can be thought of a form of pressure, kinetic pressure.

One last note: A change in the kinetic pressure of a fluid causes increased static pressure *where the fluid is slowed*. This kinetic pressure is exactly the same as the kind of pressure that your hand experiences when you put your hand outside a car, the kinetic pressure of the air pushes against your hand much harder than the ambient air pressure. The pressure exerted by a moving fluid which is distinguished from it's static pressure, say at atmospheric pressure.

Answer (score 0):

$P_i$ can be thought of as an initial pressure measurement at some point in a system that contains a flowing fluid.  $P_0$ can be thought of as another pressure measurement somewhat downstream of the initial pressure measurement.  As seen in the Bernoulli equation, changes in height of the fluid affect the pressure of the fluid at a given point.  Also note that all terms in the Bernoulli equation have dimensions of energy per unit volume, so the term $\rho v^2/2$ is kinetic energy per unit volume.

Answer (score 0):

In a static situation, each volume element has its weight balanced by the forces of the surroundings. The sideways pressure (say directions x and y) is equal at both sides of the element by symmetry. So we can write: $$-f(z+\Delta z) - mg + f(z) = 0 \implies p(z+\Delta z)\Delta x \Delta y + \rho \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z g - p(z)\Delta x \Delta y = 0$$ Dividing by the volume and letting $\Delta$'s go to zero leads to the differential equation: $$\frac{\partial p(z)}{\partial z} + \rho g = 0$$ Solving the equation and renaming the variable z as h: $$p(z) + \rho gz = cte \implies p(h_1) + \rho gh_1 = p(h_0) + \rho gh_0$$
Now, if the situation is not static, the sideways forces don't balance necessarily, and the difference of forces results in mass $\times$ acceleration:$$-f(z+\Delta z) - mg + f(z) = ma_z$$ $$-f(x+\Delta x) + f(x) = ma_x$$ $$-f(y+\Delta y) + f(y) = ma_y$$ Using the same procedure of replacing forces by pressure $\times$ area and letting $\Delta$'s go to zero, we get 3 differential equations: $$\frac{\partial p(x,y,z)}{\partial z} + \rho g + \rho \frac{dv_z}{dt} = 0$$ $$\frac{\partial p(x,y,z)}{\partial x} + \rho \frac{dv_x}{dt} = 0$$ $$\frac{\partial p(x,y,z)}{\partial y} + \rho \frac{dv_y}{dt}= 0$$

Working the first one: $$\frac{\partial p}{\partial z}dz + \rho gdz + \rho dv_z \frac{dz}{dt} = 0 \implies \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}dz + \rho gdz + \rho  v_z dv_z = 0 \implies \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}dz + \rho gdz + d(\frac{1}{2}\rho v_z^2) = 0$$

Doing the same procedure for $x$ and $y$ and adding the equations:
$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial p}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}dz + \rho gdz + d(\frac{1}{2}\rho (v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2)) = 0 \implies dp + \rho gdz + d(\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2) = 0$$

Integrating, and changing $z$ by $h$, we get:$$p_1 + \rho gh_1 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_1^2 = p_0 + \rho gh_0 + \frac{1}{2}\rho v_0^2$$